# How to Setup a Public Kafka Broker Using a Dynamic DNS?

Tags: apache-kafka, centos6, noip

I configured a Kafka Cluster with 3 brokers using 3 Zookeepers along with each broker. Figure bellow presents a graphical representation of my cluster.

[image]

A producer and consumer test in the same network using the host `192.168.0.10` worked perfectly via `kafka-console-producer` and `kafka-console-consumer` commands.

Based on that context, when I try to produce some data via `kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list DYNAMIC_DNS_ADDR:30192,DYNAMIC_DNS_ADDR:30292,DYNAMIC_DNS_ADDR:30392 --topic twitter_tweets` through the Internet, I am getting the following error:

> [2018-12-10 09:59:20,772] ERROR Error when sending message to topic twitter_tweets with key: null, value: 16 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for twitter_tweets-1: 1505 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
>   [2018-12-10 09:59:22,273] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node 1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Broker listeners are configured with the following properties:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092,SSL://0.0.0.0:9443
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.0.241:9092,SSL://192.168.0.241:9443
```

Obviously, the IP address changed in each broker for the `advertised.listeners` property. I am using `CentOS 6.10` and `Kafka 2.0.1` for that setup. A telnet test worked. Another forward to a Kafka REST Proxy port is working via the Internet and listing all topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

You need two listeners—one responding to *and advertising* the internal addresses, one for the external one.

The key thing is that *the listener that your client connects to will return the **host address and port** of that listener*.

At the moment you're spoofing your external one to your internal one, and your *external* traffic is thus hitting the *internal* listener.

You need something like this (varying the IP/hostname of the `aws_internal_listener` as required per broker):

```
KAFKA_LISTENERS: aws_internal_listener://192.168.0.241:9092,external_listener://192.168.0.241:29092

KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: aws_internal_listener://192.168.0.241:9092,external_listener://DYNAMIC_DNS_ADDR:29092

KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: aws_internal_listener:PLAINTEXT,external_listener:PLAINTEXT
KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: aws_internal_listener
```

Then your port forwarder for `DYNAMIC_DNS_ADDR` should redirect connections to 29092 on the AWS node. The key thing is that *external* connections should not end up at the listener port on the host matching the *internal* listener (which advertises an internal `192.168.0` address)

Use `kafkacat -L -b DYNAMIC_DNS_ADDR:29092` to debug and validate your config, as described [in the article here](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/).

Comment: Thank you very much, Robin Moffatt. That worked perfectly!